# Input type date passing to controller in a different format

Tags: java, mysql, spring, html

I'm trying to figure out a way around Input type=date. I am aware that the input display differs in browsers, to clarify things I'm using Google Chrome for this one. So my simple form goes like this:

```
<input type="date" name="startingdate" class="form-control" id="startingdate"/>
```

And my controller goes like this:

```
public ModelAndView getDate(@FormParam("startingdate") String startingdate) {
        System.out.println(startingdate);
}
```

The format as shown in chrome is in `mm/dd/yyyy` which is what I want, but when I get the value from html to my controller in string format it suddenly becomes `yyyy-mm-dd`.

As an example when I enter `09/11/2018`, it becomes `2018-11-09` in the controller and upon passing it to my database it becomes `0011-08-18`. Is there any other way to fix the format before my controller gets the date value without changing the date format on my database or parsing using simpledateformat?

I am under the impression that it's simply the format's fault, but if there's something I completely missed I am open to suggestions.

Thanks!

UPDATE: The actual problem was on the backend parsing of the startingdate and it went completely under my nose. Fixed the thing by using:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    java.util.Date startingdateparsed = format.parse(startdate);
    java.sql.Date startdatingparse = new java.sql.Date(startingdateparsed.getTime());
```

Thank you for your time and insights guys!

Comment: Date fields submit the date in ISO-8601 format (so it is standard) and `2018-11-09` is precisely that. Also `@FormParam` isn't from Spring so you are probably using Jersey, so not sure what you are mixing. In Spring you would use `@RequestParam` and instead of a `String` use a `Date` or `LocalDate`, Spring will do the conversion for you.

Comment: Is this behavior resulting in all browser? and did you try to make `startingdate` param as Date instead of String ?

Comment: Ah yes I made @RequestParam as Date and passed it to my server in String format via json. I just found out the parsing on my server side was the cause and am trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in the display format and the actual `value` of a `date` field in HTML5. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) as well).

So no there is no way to change the format that is send by the browser as that is strictly defined as `yyyy-MM-dd`. The display is based on the browsers locale.

In short change your backend to always parse `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of what you expect now.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using this on my backend to match it with the format from the controller 

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date startingdateparsed = format.parse(startingdate);
        java.sql.Date startingdateparse = new java.sql.Date(startingdateparsed .getTime());

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Instead of doing that just change the `String` to a `LocalDate` or `Date` in your signature and the framework will do that for you.

Comment: I've tried using LocalDate for my entity from the start but it becomes a tinyblob so I didn't use it.

Comment: Fix your mapping in your entities then (and use a ORM mapper version that supports it). You are currently doing a lot of manual work you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Guess I should test LocalDate out before using it. It looks pretty built for these kind of things, and I wouldn't need to import SimpleDateFormat, date.util, and date.sql for a run-of-the-mill date parsing.